# Macroscopic sets - a notion of largeness for Lebesgue null sets

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, geometric-measure-theory, brownian-motion, fractals

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$. We say $E$ is *$\alpha$-macroscopic*, for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$, if there exists an $\alpha$-Holder continuous function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(E)$ is of nonzero Lebesgue measure, where by convention, a $0$-Holder continuous function will simply be a continuous function.

We define the *macroscopic order* of $E$ to be the supremum of all $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ such that $E$ is $\alpha$-macroscopic.

Note that there exist macroscopic sets of zero Lebesgue measure.

**Example 1** *(Zero set of Brownian motion)*: As the primary and motivating example, the [local time](https://almostsuremath.com/2020/10/26/local-time-continuity/) of Brownian motion maps the set of zeroes of Brownian motion to an interval, and is $\alpha$-Holder continuous for all $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$.

**Example 2** (*Middle thirds Cantor set*):
The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) maps the [middle thirds Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) to an interval and is continuous, thus the middle thirds Cantor set is a $0$-macroscopic set.

**Question:** What is the relation between the the order of $E$ as a macroscopic set and its Hausdorff dimension, if any? Specifically, the following two questions are of interest - for $\alpha, r \in [0, 1]$,

1. What is the infimal/supremal Hausdorff dimension of a set of macroscopic order $\alpha$?
2. What is the infimal/supremal macroscopic order of a set of Hausdorff dimension $r$?

Comment: The definition seems to immediately imply that $\alpha \leq r$. // The cantor function is $C^\alpha$ with $\alpha = \log_3(2)$, this shows that the Cantor function has macroscopic order $\log_3(2)$.

Comment: @WillieWong Could you ellaborate a bit ? I see the other inequality from my argument below, but I do not see that $\alpha \leq r $.

Comment: Ok, see, I edited the answer so that it is complete.

Comment: @an_ordinary_mathematician: your argument is what I had in mind. [The bound turns out to be sharp if you allow domains to be general metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1189245/1543).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Frostman's lemma, if $E$ is a compact set of positive $\alpha$-Hausdorff content, then there exists a probability Borel measure $\mu$ supported in $E$ such that $\mu(I) \leq c |I|^\alpha $ for every interval $I$ and $c$ is a constant. Then the distribution function of the measure $\mu$ must be $\alpha$-Holder continuous and $f(E)=[0,1]$.

EDIT

In the other direction, if such a function $f$ exists and if $I_i$ is a cover of $E$ by open intervals, then $f(I_i)$ is a cover of $f(E)$ by intervals, hence  $ \sum_{i}|f(I_i)| \geq |f(E)|>0$, but $|f(I_i)| \leq C(f) |I_i|^\alpha $ by Holder continuity, therefore $E$ must have positive $\alpha$- Hausdorff content.

Comment: Oh, so they are the same. Tbh, that is a bit disappointing… but thank you for the slick answer!